# save jquery isotope filtering history

Tags: jquery, save, history

I'm using Jquery isotope, to filter products on my homepage.

on my page: http://osaiart.no/terrazzolys.php

I have different categories for the products. The problem is, if you click on a different category than the first one, and then click a product. It wont recogize what category you were on, when you hit the back button.

Is it a way to make it recognize what category you were on when you go back?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's any specific method provided from isotope itself but here's what I'd do. use javascript cookie to store the the value of the selected category. and then on page load you can just filter out other products like this

```
$('#container').isotope({ filter: '.selected' });
//filter out other products and show the only category that has the .selected class
```

here's a cookie plugin that I usually go for https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie
and for further implementation like control the filtering with back button etc. you can use html5's history api or a plugin like this for simple implementation - https://github.com/balupton/jquery-history